# Getting exact File Path with File Upload to send file via Email C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, file-upload, path

I want to send a file via email using c# ASP.net (Maybe more files too, but for the moment I'm concerned about sending at least only one file)

For the moment, I do have a method that does work if you want to send an Email

```
public string EnviarMensaje(int intIdVendedor, string strCorreoPara, string strCorreosAdicionales, string strTema, string strMensaje, string strRuta)
    {
        string strResultado="";
        DataTable dt = ConexionBD.GetInstanciaConexionBD().GetVendedorEspecifico(intIdVendedor);
        string strCuerpo = strMensaje + "\n\n\n\nMensaje Enviado Por:\n" + dt.Rows[0]["Vendedor"] + "\n" + dt.Rows[0]["Email"] + "\n" + dt.Rows[0]["Telefono"];
        string[] strListaCorreos = strCorreosAdicionales.Split(new Char[] {' ', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net");

            mail.Subject = strTema;
            mail.Body = strCuerpo;
            mail.From = new MailAddress(strCorreoDe);
            mail.To.Add(strCorreoPara);

            foreach (string c in strListaCorreos)
            {
                mail.To.Add(c);
            }

            if (strRuta != "")
            {
                Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new Attachment(strRuta);
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            SmtpServer.Port = 80;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strCorreoDe, strContrasena);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            strResultado = "Exito";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strResultado = ex.ToString();
        }

        return strResultado;
    }
```

in aspx I have

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadArchivos" runat="server" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEnviar" runat="server" Height="60px" Width="60px" ImageUrl="~/img/iconos/email.png" CausesValidation = "True" ValidationGroup="vgpCorreo" onclick="imgBtnEnviar_Click" />
```

and on the cs I have

```
EnviarEmail objEmail = new EnviarEmail();

protected void imgBtnEnviar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
if (fileUploadArchivos.HasFile)
{
    strArchivo = Path.GetTempFileName();\\RIGHT NOW I LEFT IT THIS WAY, BUT I NOW THAT HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I DON'T KNOW WHTAT CAN I DO HERE
}
string strResultado = objEmail.EnviarMensaje((int)Session["IdVendedor"], lblCorreoPara.Text, tbxCorreoPara.Text, tbxTema.Text, tbxMensaje.Text, strArchivo);
```

}

However, the problem is in a FileUpload.
I have tried many methods like, Server.MapPath, Path.GetFileName, GetDirectoryName, GetFullPath, GetPathRoot... and I'm always getting either nothing, only the filename or a completely different path (I guess is a server kind of path)..

I only for the moment want to get a file path as simple as C:\Test.txt for example...
I suppose that if I can get that exact string from the FileUpload, I'll be able to send it... However, I can't figure out how to make it work.

Hope you can help me
Thanks

Comment: I don't see a `FileUpload` anywhere - where is it? Where do you get `strRuta` from?

Comment: sorry, I already edited it, thank you for me letting me know =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a local copy of the file uploaded kept on the server you can just do

```
fuFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filepath));
```

Then your strRuta can use the file you just saved via

```
strRuta = Server.MapPath(filepath);
```

ready to pass into the new Attachment object.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your method and it did work, now I have another question...

first I upload the file (let's say a txt file), I then get the Path, and I am able to send the file via email...

However, I want to delete the file afterwards so it doesn't stay on the server... but when I use 
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + fileUploadArchivos.FileName);

it states that I cannot delete the file since it is being used by another program...

Any suggestions there??        Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the file *at all* to disk, not if all you want to do with it is add it as an attachment.

`FileUpload` has a [`FileContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) property that is a `Stream` - some of the constructors of the [`Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.attachment) class take a stream as a parameter.

The solution is to pass this stream to your method and use it directly.

In code behind:

```
string strResultado = objEmail.EnviarMensaje((int)Session["IdVendedor"], 
                                             lblCorreoPara.Text, 
                                             tbxCorreoPara.Text, 
                                             tbxTema.Text, 
                                             tbxMensaje.Text, 
                                             fileUploadArchivos.FileContent);
```

In your class:

```
public string EnviarMensaje(int intIdVendedor, 
                            string strCorreoPara, 
                            string strCorreosAdicionales, 
                            string strTema, 
                            string strMensaje, 
                            Stream attachmentData)
{

...

  var attachment = new Attachment(attachmentData, "nameOfAttachment");

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, using a stream instead of a simple text:

```
public string EnviarMensaje(int intIdVendedor, string strCorreoPara, string strCorreosAdicionales, string strTema, string strMensaje, string strRuta)
    {
        string strResultado="";
        DataTable dt = ConexionBD.GetInstanciaConexionBD().GetVendedorEspecifico(intIdVendedor);
        string strCuerpo = strMensaje + "\n\n\n\nMensaje Enviado Por:\n" + dt.Rows[0]["Vendedor"] + "\n" + dt.Rows[0]["Email"] + "\n" + dt.Rows[0]["Telefono"];
        string[] strListaCorreos = strCorreosAdicionales.Split(new Char[] {' ', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net");

            mail.Subject = strTema;
            mail.Body = strCuerpo;
            mail.From = new MailAddress(strCorreoDe);
            mail.To.Add(strCorreoPara);

            foreach (string c in strListaCorreos)
            {
                mail.To.Add(c);
            }

            bool hasAttachment = !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(strRuta);
            System.IO.FileStream stream = null;
            Attachment attachment = null;

            if (hasAttachment)
            {
                // Create a file stream.
                stream = new FileStream(strRuta, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                // Define content type.
                ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
                contentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain; // or whatever your attachment is

                // Create the attachment and add it.
                attachment = new Attachment(stream, contentType);
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            SmtpServer.Port = 80;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strCorreoDe, strContrasena);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            strResultado = "Exito";

            // Don't forget to release the resources if the attachment has been added
            if (hasAttachment)
            {
                data.Dispose();
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strResultado = ex.ToString();
        }

        return strResultado;
    }
```